# Overlaying different species accumulation plots

Tags: r, plot, vegan

I want to plot some species accumulation curves in R that can overlay on top of each other in a grey-scale format, whilst being easily interpreted. [Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=specaccum&espv=2&biw=1440&bih=815&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAgQ_AUoA2oVChMIt5-_zLmFxwIVSVQUCh2rvgeZ#imgrc=PsBWfSwaUskXbM%3A) is a link to the type of plot I would like to output, with polygons possessing different types of grey and a degree of transparency, with lines possessing different `lty` values. Some example data:

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1, 3*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=3))
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:2, 4*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=4))
library(vegan)
spec1 <- specaccum(df1)
spec2 <- specaccum(df2)
```

Here is as far as I've got with the `plot` so far (not great example data but the underlying principle holds true):

```
plot(spec2, ci.type = "polygon", ci.lty = 0, ci.col = "grey")
plot(spec1, ci.type = "polygon", ci.lty = 0, ci.col = "gray50",add= TRUE)
```

When I try and change `lty`, it says:

> Error in polygon(c(xaxvar, rev(xaxvar)), c(x$richness - ci * x$sd, rev(x$richness +  : 
>     formal argument "lty" matched by multiple actual arguments.

I am not sure how to overcome this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Changing `ci.lty` seems to work for me. What are the parameters that you would like to input in the plot?

Comment: ci.lty changes the polygon outline for me. What I would like is two polygons (but transparent enough that you can see the one behind) and two different line types. So like the example but with only two factors. Thank you.

Comment: is the 'shape' of the polygon correct? You only need the transparency?

Comment: I presume the default shape is fine. The data was quite a poor example of shape though compared to my own samples.

Comment: I added an answer for the transparency and one line type, you can check different rgb values in many places on the web, here is one for example: http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your data, you need to change the `ci.col` parameter to an `rgb()` color specification with an `alpha` value for transparency ([see here for details](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/rgb.html), -bear in mind that, according to the documentation, the transparency might not be supported in all devices):

```
plot(spec2, ci.type = "polygon", ci.lty = 0, ci.col = rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5))
plot(spec1, ci.type = "polygon", ci.lty = 1, ci.col = rgb(.5, .5, .5, 0.5),add= TRUE).
```

This will give you the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Anytime! Note that, per your specifications, the plots are gray, but you can change the colors with rbg formatting